# clustering data with date timestamp

Tags: time-series, timestamp, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a time-series dataset that contains 10 features in addition to the "timestamp" column (the index of the data frame)
after scaling the features' values and implementing k-means clustering, I got the results as an np.array.
My problem is that I need to know what is the timestamp of each sample in a cluster. How can I keep the timestamp index while clustering without using it as a feature ??

Answer (score 0):

Naive and easy, but in my opinion fine solution would be to make a new index to the original dataframe - just a row number - and then split the dataframe into two separate ones - one with the timestamp and the other one with the features. Then you could easily reassign the results to the timestamps, since fit_predict will keep the order.